# 100 % CPU Usage when run android studio 2.1.1

Tags: android-studio

I have installed the latest update of android studio 2.1.1 and when i try to run my code the laptop cpu usage is 100% and it takes a lot of time, can any one tell me what to do now?

Comment: This sounds entirely normal, and I'm inclined to suggest that the only solution is to upgrade to a more powerful computer. Even then, if you are compiling large projects, you will find your CPU usage at 100% when compiling, and sometimes when executing your code. Did you have this issue on older versions of Android Studio? Or is 2.1.1 the first one you've tried?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I try to run my code"? Running the app using the emulator or a real device or the process that compiles the app? Does it go away? Is your laptop super slow and how long is "a lot of time"? Does it happen with a different version of Android Studio?

Comment: @XtrmJosh the specs of my laptop is good , Core i7 with 6GB Ram, so I assume it is a powerful laptop, no this issue appear after I upgrade android studio to latest version 2.1.1, When I open Task Manager, I found from 3 to 5 tasks for Java SE Library, one of them consume about 50% of CPU Usage, I don't know why

Comment: @zapl I am running my application on real device, and my laptop specs is good, and it is not slow by default, the CPU consumption is only 7% to 20% when I close android studio, I am also installing a very limited number of programs, android studio, eclipse, smartgit , office, notebad++, etc

Comment: 7-20% is fairly high in idle for an i7 laptop. Are you maybe in a powersave mode that throttles the cpu? edit: mine is at 5% when not plugged in, so maybe it's not as unnormal as I thought.

Comment: @zapl so what you think that I should do now ?

Comment: I guess I would go back to an older version of AS. Or you can try to identify the cause by profiling it: http://blog.takipi.com/oracle-java-mission-control-the-ultimate-guide/  - maybe there is a bug you can report or something else to fix.

Comment: @zapl I have downloaded a new clean copy of windows and I am still facing the same problem

Comment: I'm seeing the same on my machine, Android Studio 2.1.2 on a MacBook (i7 2.6GHz) where cpu usage becomes very high during the day. It seems that some if it is from the `java` process it self, as that process kept running havoc yesterday after i had shutdown AS. But i don't have any actual data on how and why.

Comment: @oiZo : have solved the problem, please check my edit.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail: Unless your machine actually has 45GB of ram to allocate, i strongly doubt that those numbers are helping.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing solutions into the question is not.